# Snakemake says list index is out of range even when sections of code are not accessed

Tags: python-3.x, snakemake

I had a strange error occur today, and I am able to reproduce it with the following example:

```
files = ["A.txt", "B.txt"]


rule all:
    input: "copied_joined.txt"

rule A:
    input: files
    output: "joined.txt"
    shell: "cat {input} >> {output}"


rule B:
    input:
        data=rules.A.output
    output: "copied_joined.txt"
    shell:
        """
        if [[ {input} == "joined.txt" ]]; then
            echo "Running on {input}!"
            cp {input.data[0]} {output}
        elif {input} == "garbage_string" ]]; then
            echo "Running on garbage!"
            cp {input.data[1]} {output}
        fi
        """
```

In `rule B`, the `elif` section is never reached, but Snakemake still shows an error `IndexError: list index out of range`, because I am accessing `input.data[1]`, which doesn't exist.

In my specific use case, I am using an input function that will provide one or two files based on wildcards. I am then performing specific actions on the files, similar to the if/elif above, which causes Snakemake to fail. Removing the `cp {input.data[1]} {output}` resolves the issue

To resolve my own issue, if I was originally going to return a single file, I returned two copies of the same file, such as:

```py
def input_data(wildcards):
    if something_true:
        file_one = "ONE.txt"
        return "ONE.txt", "TWO.txt"
    else:
        return "THREE.txt", "THREE.txt"
```

My hacky solution works, but I was wondering if there was a more agrred-upon fix for this?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my solution by removing the brackets `[]` from the `input`. The new code is as follows:

```
files = ["A.txt", "B.txt"]


rule all:
    input: "copied_joined.txt"

rule A:
    input: files
    output: "joined.txt"
    shell: "cat {input} >> {output}"


rule B:
    input:
        data=rules.A.output
    output: "copied_joined.txt"
    shell:
        """
        if [[ {input} == "joined.txt" ]]; then
            echo "Running on {input}!"
            cp {input.data} {output}
        elif {input} == "garbage_string" ]]; then
            echo "Running on garbage!"
            cp {input.data} {output}
        fi
        """
```

This may not work with the `cp` command, but the general gist is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to handle lists and if-else's in python than in bash. For example you could consider something like (check for syntax errors, etc):

```
rule B:
    input:
        data=rules.A.output
    output: "copied_joined.txt"
    run:
        if len(input.data) == 1:
            shell("cp {input.data[0]} {output}") # Or use only python code if you only need to copy files
        elif len(input.data) == 2:
            shell("cp {input.data[1]} {output}")
        else:
            sys.exit("This should not happen")
```

---

Unrelated, this bit in rule A:

```
shell: "cat {input} >> {output}"
```

note that snakemake deletes `{output}` before running the rule so you don't really append `{input}` to `{output}` as you would expect from looking at that shell command. If you really need to append, maybe post a separate question.